# When I use openlayers3 to embed a map with Openstreetmap, what API of Openstreetmap is being used?

Tags: openstreetmap, openlayers-3

I need to use openlayers3 to embed a map in webpage, and I am using tiles from openstreetmap.org, so what API of openstreetmap am I using? The data API or the Image API of something like that?

Also, what license should I use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OpenLayers, Leaflet and similar libraries display [tiles](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tiles) in the background. These are just images.

The license of these tiles depends on the tile server you are using. If you are using tile.openstreetmap.org then take a look at the [OSM tile usage policy](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tile_usage_policy) and [Copyright](https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright/). The latter page states:

> The cartography in our map tiles, and our documentation, are licensed
>   under the Creative Commons Attribution-ShareAlike 2.0 license (CC
>   BY-SA).

Note that this applies only to the *tiles* provided by tile.openstreetmap.org. Other tile servers will have other licenses and other tile usage policies.

Don't confuse this with raw OSM *data* which is licensed under Open Data Commons Open Database Lizenz (ODbL). However since you are only going to display *tiles* the ODbL doesn't apply to you.

Comment: Thanks a lot. You really helped me!